# Unable to turn off cold water flow in airconditioner, possibly due to solenoid valve

Tags: plumbing, air-conditioning, valve

We had an accident with air conditioner yesterday where controller mounted to the wall shortcut and broke. I had to turn off electricity switch for airconditioner, but woke up this morning realising that cold water is flowing through its pipes and radiator despite it being off, its a Fan coil unit air condition.

This is manual for the air conditioning unit in question: http://estervil.com/img/OBIAVI/Basic_Geko_53.pdf

My first instinct was that there is something wrong with valve thats supposed to cut of cold water flow, I tried twisting it around, but don't think it is helping. I am also unable to to find anything online about it, but it has these red switches at the bottom, maybe thats how I can manually turn it off? I'm not sure about how they are used.

Valve in question is below (there are wires going into it behind):

[image]

Comment: Did you turn off the circuit breaker for the outside unit as well?

Comment: Where does the cold water come from?  If this is a multi-tenant building with building supplied refrigeration it’s possible that it will always flow.

Comment: @Tyson it is, however I never noticed this prior to the incident. There is a bit of condensation accumulating there, is this normal? And if water is always supposed to flow through, why is this valve in there?

Comment: @LimoDRIVER That one is controlled by the building I guess, according to comments left by others, so I have no access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an air conditioner *at all*.  It's nothing but a radiator in a fancy dress.

The unit is designed to be supplied chilled water at 6-12°C (43-54°F) and blow it across a - well, a radiator.  It has a tray to catch condensation.  And that's about all there is to the unit.

So it's totally dependent on external machinery supply chilled water to it, and this machinery is fairly complex. Which tells me you are in a multi-unit apartment/condo building **with maintenance staff who tend to that equipment**. Since this equipment is only the "head unit" for that system, and you don't control that system, you need to talk to the superintendent. They fix these things all the time and probably have spares in stock, which is good since you'd have trouble finding these at retail.

Comment: Indeed this is one of those situations. Is it normal for water to always flow through the radiator? And in terms of controller we already scheduled a maintenance, I was concerned about it still being cold, as I never paid attention to this.